# Preventing Selection of Future Dates with jQuery or Java

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm very new to website building and I'm trying to build validation into a form that employees will submit. I want to prevent them selecting dates in the future for a particular field. None of the suggested solutions I've read in the other posts have worked for me so far. Believe me I've been at this a longer that I would like to admit trying everything I could find. I would greatly appreciate some help in figuring out what I am doing wrong. Here are the sections of my code that will hopefully be enough to see what is going on.

```
<head>
 <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $(function(){
            $("#purchasedate").datepicker({
            maxDate: '0',
            format: 'mm-dd-yyyy'
            }); 
            });
 </script>
 <script 
   src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/
   jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js">
 </script>
</head>

<body>
 <section>
  <form method="post" action="#">
   <p>Purchase Date</p>
   <input class="purchasedate" 
    type="date" 
    name="purchaseDate" 
    value="" 
   />
  </form>
 </section>
<body>
```

I've tried using maxDate: new Date(). I've tried it without the ready function or the function enclosing the datepicker. When previewing the page the calendar pops up to select a date but future dates are still available. Thanks for the help.

Comment: i got your code, erased $(function() { line, and worked, I can only select the actual day or a past one =/ here is the jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/tuk4pob3/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try something like this :

You have to replace your script tag in the header by this one :

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
    <title>Data sharemedia</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js" integrity="sha256-VazP97ZCwtekAsvgPBSUwPFKdrwD3unUfSGVYrahUqU=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>

<body>
<section>
  <form method="post" action="#">
   <p>Purchase Date</p>
  <input type="text" id="datepicker">
  </form>
 </section>

</body>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
            $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({ maxDate: new Date });

    });
</script>

</html>
```

Comment: Pardon my not know knowing but I put this in the header of my HTML file right?

Comment: Yes, you have to replace your script tag in the header by the on i gave on the answer,

See the answer, i've edited it.

Comment: I tried replacing the current script with your code but I can still select future dates when testing the page. Any other thoughts on what i might be missing?

Comment: Thanks for the entire code. When I transition it into the html document I'm working however it stops working... I will keep trying to get it to transition properly. Could anything else in my page possibly interfere with it?

Comment: I went through line by line adding my code into your solution until I found the offending line of code that broke it. Now it works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, change the order of the scripts. Call the jquery, and any other plugins that uses this jquery after this one. Later, add your scripts. That will save you headaches.

Secondly, remove the `$(function(){` line, as it's doing nothing right now. And it should be fine.

I got the jsfiddle of it right here: https://jsfiddle.net/tuk4pob3/

I just copied your code with the changes I told you and I can only select dates from past until the present day. The only thing I changed is the `type` of the input.

Comment: I gave this a try but it still didn't work for me. I will also ask you if there might be anything else that could be interfering with it.